# Consulta con fecha vacia

Tags: sql, ms-access

Quiero hacer una consulta cuyo resultado saque una columna que siempre ponga "SI", otra con la fecha de hoy y otra con una columna vacía en formato fecha, que me servirá más adelante cuando exporte el fichero.

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta sería algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé si se puede meter una columna con formato fecha que esté vacía.

Había pensado dejarlo como texto en blanco y al exportarlo definirlo como fecha.

Pero por curiosidad no sé si se puede hacer directamente.

Tal vez diseñando la consulta en modo SQL se pueda.

Comment: Hola. Vas a tener que aclarar más lo que necesitas dado que por ejemplo hablas de exportar los resultados de la consulta, pero no especificas con que extensión quieres exportar ya que es medio extraño eso de querer un campo sin datos y teóricamente sí con formato.

Comment: Exportar a csv o xlsx. Si que es extraño. Es por saber si se puede por simple curiosidad.  Ya que luego tengo a abrir el fichero exportado con otro software y añadirle más datos y me vendría bien que reconozca esa columna vacía como fecha

Comment: ¿Sabías que los campos/columnas de los archivos csv no tienen en específico un formato y que en Excel el formato predeterminado es el "General" y por obvias? ¿Por qué? Porque el primero es un tipo de archivo de texto plano y el segundo es un programa del tipo hoja de cálculo, no un sistema gestor de base de datos. Saludos.